# Number of non-retractable boundary loops on the torus

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb{T}$ be the two-dimensional torus. Let $S\subsetneqq \mathbb{T}$ be a connected subset whose boundary is a disjoint union of finitely many Jordan curves (loops). We call these loops the boundary loops of $S$.

Any loop on the torus is said to be null-homotopoic if it can be continuously deformed to a point on the torus. Let $N$ be the collection of non-null-homotopoic boundary loops of $S$. Prove or disprove the following statement:

If $N\neq\emptyset$, then $N$ contains exactly two loops.

Comment: Yes, it can be continuously deformed into a point.

Comment: By "union" you probably mean "disjoint union." And the terminology "retractible" is nonstandard, it is normally called "null-homotopic".

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Sorry I am not very versed in topology. I changed the terminology to null-homotopic. For non-null-homotpoic loops, I mean those wrapping around the torus which "cannot be pinched to a point".

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks, I made the changes.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is wrong. Consider the case where $S$ is given as
$$S=\left(\left[\frac{1}{5},\frac{2}{5}\right]\times[0,1]\right)\cup \left(\left[\frac{3}{5},\frac{4}{5}\right]\times[0,1]\right)$$
in the flat torus. Then, the boundary consists of four non retractable cycles given by $\lbrace\frac{1}{5}\rbrace\times[0,1]$, $\lbrace\frac{2}{5}\rbrace\times[0,1]$, $\lbrace\frac{3}{5}\rbrace\times[0,1]$ and $\lbrace\frac{4}{5}\rbrace\times[0,1]$.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, I should have said $S$ is connected. It is an overlook on my side. I've added this condition to the statement of the question.